# Cannot import name 'functional_datapipe' from 'torch.utils.data'

Tags: python, pytorch, package, google-colaboratory, torchtext

When I am running datasets_utils.py from '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torchtext/data/datasets_utils.py' in Google Colab, the following error occurs even with the most updated versions of Python packages:

ImportError: cannot import name 'functional_datapipe' from 'torch.utils.data' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/**init**.py)

Are there any solutions to solve such errors, as I could not find functional_datapipe even in the official torch.utils.data documentation? The following is excerpt from datasets._utils.py in the Google Colab environment

```
import functools
import inspect
import os
import io
import torch
from torchtext.utils import (
    validate_file,
    download_from_url,
    extract_archive,
)
from torch.utils.data import functional_datapipe, IterDataPipe
from torch.utils.data.datapipes.utils.common import StreamWrapper
import codecs
```

Answer (score 2):

It might be available only on [torchdata.datapipes](https://pytorch.org/data/beta/index.html)

Comment: But there is still no such function in that library. It is still confusing because even local Python 3.8 site-packages/torch/utils/data/__init__.py contain functional_datapipe and IterDataPipe.\

Comment: There is also one more issue: the line "from torch.utils.data.datapipes.utils.common import StreamWrapper" keeps getting issues besides the above lines. How such errors can occur considering they have been imported from site packages?

Comment: How is it related to the functional_datapipe from torchtext? I presume they are different though